# Apps with same name in Google playstore

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

We are in the process of decommissioning our app and publishing another app with the same name. The playstore has a criteria that apps must have unique names. So would it be enough to just change the name of the app in the play store listing to something else like myApp-old to satisfy the unique name criteria or should we also update the app(new version) with different name.

Answer (score 3):

The name does not matter. In Android, the important thing is the `Package name`.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly,
The package of your project needs to be different.
for example "com.google.app"